# scipy, fftpack and float64

Tags: python, 64-bit, scipy

I would like to use the dct functionality from the scipy.fftpack with an array of numpy float64. However, it seems it is only implemented for np.float32. Is there any quick workaround I could do to get this done? I looked into it quickly but I am not sure of all the dependencies. So, before messing everything up, I thought I'd ask for tips here!

The only thing I have found so far about this is this link : http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-svn/2010-September/004197.html

Thanks in advance.

Here is the ValueError it raises:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-f09567c28e37> in <module>()
----> 1 scipy.fftpack.dct(c[100])

/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/fftpack/realtransforms.pyc in dct(x, type, n, axis, norm, overwrite_x)
    118         raise NotImplementedError(
    119               "Orthonormalization not yet supported for DCT-I")
--> 120     return _dct(x, type, n, axis, normalize=norm, overwrite_x=overwrite_x)
    121 
    122 def idct(x, type=2, n=None, axis=-1, norm=None, overwrite_x=0):

/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/fftpack/realtransforms.pyc in _dct(x, type, n, axis, overwrite_x, normalize)
    215             raise ValueError("Type %d not understood" % type)
    216     else:
--> 217         raise ValueError("dtype %s not supported" % tmp.dtype)
    218 
    219     if normalize:

ValueError: dtype >f8 not supported
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not the double precision. Double precision is of course supported. The problem is that you have a little endian computer and (maybe loading a file from a file?) have big endian data, note the `>` in `dtype >f8 not supported`. It seems you will simply have to cast it to native double yourself. If you know its double precision, you probably just want to convert everytiong to your native order once:

```
c = c.astype(float)
```

Though I guess you could also check `c.dtype.byteorder` which I think should be `'='`, and if, switch... something along:

```
if c.dtype.byteorder != '=':
    c = c.astype(c.dtype.newbyteorder('='))
```

Which should work also if you happen to have single precision or integers...