# Fourier smoothing of data set

Tags: python, scipy, fft, smoothing

I am following [this link](http://galassi.org/mark/course-2006/fourier-smooth.py) to do a smoothing of my data set.
The technique is based on the principle of removing the higher order terms of the Fourier Transform of the signal, and so obtaining a smoothed function.
This is part of my code:

```
N = len(y)

y = y.astype(float)               # fix issue, see below
yfft = fft(y, N)

yfft[31:] = 0.0                   # set higher harmonics to zero
y_smooth = fft(yfft, N)

ax.errorbar(phase, y, yerr = err, fmt='b.', capsize=0, elinewidth=1.0)
ax.plot(phase, y_smooth/30, color='black') #arbitrary normalization, see below
```

However some things do not work properly.
Indeed, you can check the resulting plot :
[image]
The blue points are my data, while the black line should be the smoothed curve.

First of all I had to convert my array of data `y` by following [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12308336/2107030).

Second, I just normalized arbitrarily to compare the curve with data, since I don't know why the original curve had values much higher than the data points.

Most importantly, the curve is like "specular" to the data point, and I don't know why this happens.
It would be great to have some advices especially to the third point, and more generally how to optimize the smoothing with this technique for my particular data set shape.

Answer (score 14):

Your problem is probably due to the shifting that the standard FFT does. You can read about it [here.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftshift.html)

Your data is real, so you can take advantage of symmetries in the FT and use the special function `np.fft.rfft`

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(40)
y = np.log(x + 1) * np.exp(-x/8.) * x**2 + np.random.random(40) * 15
rft = np.fft.rfft(y)
rft[5:] = 0   # Note, rft.shape = 21
y_smooth = np.fft.irfft(rft)

plt.plot(x, y, label='Original')
plt.plot(x, y_smooth, label='Smoothed')
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()
```

If you plot the absolute value of rft, you will see that there is almost no information in frequencies beyond 5, so that is why I choose that threshold (and a bit of playing around, too).

Here the results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather you want to build a low pass filter by doing the following:

1. Move to the frequency domain. (Fourier transform)
2. Remove undesired frequencies.
3. Move back to the time domain. (Inverse fourier transform)

Looking at your code, instead of doing 3) you're just doing another fourier transform. Instead, try doing an actual inverse fourier transform to move back to the time domain:

```
y_smooth = ifft(yfft, N)
```

Have a look at [scipy signal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) to see a bunch of already available filters.

(Edit: I'd be curious to see the results, do share!)

Comment: Mathematically, FT is its own inverse, modulo some minus signs that depend on the definition, and I think that is why the OP used that. Of course, the devil is in the details, and it looks like the one used, plus the frequency shifting, means that $FT[FT[f](x)](k) = f(-x)$. See my answer for an image output.

Answer (score 0):

I would be very cautious in using this technique. By zeroing out frequency components of the FFT you are effectively constructing a brick wall filter in the frequency domain. This will result in convolution with a sinc in the time domain and likely distort the information you want to process. Look up "Gibbs phenomenon" for more information.

You're probably better off designing a low pass filter or using a simple N-point moving average (which is itself a LPF) to accomplish the smoothing.